# Python Pandas: selecting rows based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame in the following format:

```
df.head()

        y   y_pred
599     0   0
787     9   9
47      2   2
1237    1   1
1069    6   6
```

I want to find the rows / index numbers - where y != y_pred.

I am trying to do it through `Select` but am not able to do so. Please help.

TIA

Comment: I reopen question because it is about filtering, but difference is output is `index`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = df.query('y != y_pred').index
```

Sample:

```
print (df)
      y  y_pred
599   0       1 <-values changed for match
787   9       9
47    2       2
1237  1       1
1069  6       3 <-values changed for match

df = df.query('y != y_pred').index
print (df)
Int64Index([599, 1069], dtype='int64')
```

Solutions with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) are:

```
df1 = df[df.y != df.y_pred].index
print (df1)
Int64Index([599, 1069], dtype='int64')
```

Or another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43147280/2901002).

For check different values:

```
print (df.query('y != y_pred'))
      y  y_pred
599   0       1
1069  6       3

print (df[df.y != df.y_pred])
      y  y_pred
599   0       1
1069  6       3
```

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df.index[df.y != df.y_pred]
```

---

Let's alter your sample data

```
df.iloc[0, 0] = 1
df.iloc[3, 1] = 0
print(df)

      y  y_pred
599   1       0
787   9       9
47    2       2
1237  1       0
1069  6       6
```

Then try our code

```
df.index[df.y != df.y_pred]

Int64Index([599, 1237], dtype='int64')
```

---

For more efficiency, use the underlying `numpy` arrays

```
df.index.values[df.y.values != df.y_pred.values]

array([ 599, 1237])
```

you can return the `df` subset with

```
df.loc[(df.y != df.y_pred).values]

      y  y_pred
599   1       0
1237  1       0
```